# Создать таблицу с возможностью выбора множества значений

Tags: javascript, html, table

Мне нужно создать таблицу со значениями, в которой по нажатию на клетки они будут выделяться (Дальше предоставлю пример как я это вижу). После выделения всех нужных значений нужно их вывести в массив.

Считаю что `<select>` или `dropdown` не подходят, т к мне нужно именно в виде таблицы

Я не могу предоставить своего варианта решения, поскольку моего опыта не хватает на то чтобы даже подступится к этой задаче.

Вот пример того что мне нужно получить:

**Начальная таблица:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Одно выделение ячейки в таблице:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Множество выделений ячеек в таблице:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И после этого должен вывестись массив

```
res = ['A', 'G', 'N']
```

То есть массив с выбранными значениями

Comment: Посмотрите такой [готовый вариант](https://incode.pro/jquery/vydelenie-jacheek-tablitsy-jquery-plagin-cellselection.html). Если даже не его использовать, то как минимум, там можно посмотреть принцип работы.

Comment: Не совсем то что мне нужно. Однако мне предложили вариант сделать при помощи создания таблицы кастомных чекбоксов

Comment: Верстаете таблицу. При нажатии на ячейку навешиваете ей определенный атрибут, например класс. А после пробегаетесь forEach по всем элементам где имеется этот атрибут и получаете значения

Comment: @Lcashe, можно и так, как вам предложили, но `KordDEM` посоветовал более рациональный вариант с классом, т.к. он будет служить не только маркером отмеченной ячейки для сбора данных, но и классом со стилями для подсветки выбранных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример как можно сделать кликабельную таблицу с записью выбранных значений.

```js
    // Запрашиваем размеры(если надо)
    const rows = prompt('Сколько линий?');
    const cols = prompt('Сколько столбцов?');
    let clicks = []; // Храним выбранные значения
    let numbers = 0; // Это выводимые значения. Для примера использую цифры
    const elem = document.getElementById('pole'); // Берем родительский элемент
    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) { // Для каждой строки
        const tr = document.createElement('tr'); // Создаем строку таблицы
        for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) { // Для каждого столбца
            const td = document.createElement('td'); // Создаем столбец
            const pos = numbers++; // Сохраняем значение 
            td.innerText = pos; // Записываем значение в ячейку
            td.classList.add('sqr'); // присваиваем класс

            td.addEventListener('click', () => { // Создаем событие нажатия на кнопку
                // Если значения нет, добавляем, иначе удаляем из массива
                clicks.indexOf(pos) === -1 ? clicks.push(pos) : clicks = clicks.filter(it => it !== pos);
                td.classList.toggle('selected'); // меняем класс
                console.log(clicks); // Вывод значений из массива(для демонстрации)
            });
            tr.appendChild(td); // Добавляем ячейку в строку
        }
        elem.appendChild(tr); // Добавляем строку в таблицу
    }
```

```css
.sqr {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }

    .sqr:hover {
        background-color: aqua;
    }

    .selected {
        background-color: chartreuse;
    }
    table {
        display: block;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }

    table td {
        border: 1px solid;
    }
```

```html
<table id="pole"></table>
```

Comment: Именно то что нужно