# Как создавать динамически HTML код и вставлять на страницу?

Tags: javascript

Как создавать динамически HTML код и вставлять на страницу с учетом вложенности и переменных JS?
В итоге вот такой код должен бы получиться:

```
<table class="table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th> Наименование </th>
   <th> Колличество </th>
   <th> Цена за ед. </th>
   <th> Сумма </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td> Клей </td>
   <td> 22 </td>
   <td> 100 </td>
   <td> 2200 </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Что я смог сделать:

```js
    let naumenovanie = "Клей";
  let coll = 22;
  let price = 100;
  let itogo = 2200;
  let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    let td = document.createElement('td');
    let tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
  
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
    tr.appendChild(th);
```

```html
<table class="table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th> Наименование </th>
   <th> Колличество </th>
   <th> Цена за ед. </th>
   <th> Сумма </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Но как сделать вложенность и вставить все значения не могу понять.

Comment: Ну подсмотрите вот тут например. Как раз [собирали динамически таблицу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1480745/1480940#1480940)

Comment: Вообще, такие таблицы должны с сервера приходить, ну и хотя бы данные с них. А вот с чём у вас проблемы возникли я не понимаю... Вроде вы до этого всё правильно написали, почему же дальше не можете?

Comment: Иногда дается все легко а вот иногда ступор и не могу понять что не так )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let naumenovanie = "Клей";
let coll = 22;
let price = 100;
let itogo = 2200;

let tr = document.createElement('tr');

let tdName = document.createElement('td');
tdName.textContent = naumenovanie;
let tdCol = document.createElement('td');
tdCol.textContent = coll;
let tdPrice = document.createElement('td');
tdPrice.textContent = price;
let tdSumm = document.createElement('td');
tdSumm = itogo;

tr.append(tdName);
tr.append(tdCol);
tr.append(tdPrice);
tr.append(tdSumm);

let tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
tbody.appendChild(tr);
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Наименование </th>
      <th> Колличество </th>
      <th> Цена за ед. </th>
      <th> Сумма </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Для множества строк - надо будет применять цикл, а данные брать из массива

Comment: Так чего же вы его сами не применили?)

Comment: А зачем? Пока вопрос не в этом. Я вижу что у автора пока просто проблема с нормальным формированием таблицы

Comment: Алексей, спасибо )

Comment: Все таки с циклом я запутался, добавил цикл простановки значений ячеек `let arr = [tdName, tdCol, tdPrice, tdSumm]; arr.forEach(function (entry) {tr.append(entry); return; });` Но как сделать так же но для строки не могу сообразить.

Comment: https://codepen.io/_Poetiq_/pen/YzjyvMa